# Assemble webpage from different sources

Tags: php, angularjs, node.js, merge, reactjs

My team is working on a project of merging two sites into one site.

Each of the site is written in different technologies.

### One site:

PHP/Angular

### Other site:

Node.js/React.js

We don't want to rewrite either of the sites.

The reason we are doing it, is because both sites were developed in different companies and recently the companies were M&Aed

In the merged site we should have the same Headers and Footers, the headers has business logic which relevant to the logged in user, and to the page he is visiting.

Beside the Headers and Footer the content will be served by either of the sites but not both.

I was wondering how would you merge the sites?

Thanks

Comment: having multiple framework on the same page could make you crazy..mixup them upto some extend would make sense(but that should have strong reason for that specific case)..

Comment: I, personally, would rewrite one of the two. Unless they're going to remain separate systems this is going to be endlessly confusing and it will end up causing more trouble than rebuilding one of the two in the first place.

Comment: thanks, will your answer  be the same even if  the content of the  site besides the footer or the header is served from only one of  the sites?

Comment: For each app add header and footer code to pull in the data from the server?

Comment: Which server? both servers?